# OSX Yosemite can't resize partitions?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

A few weeks ago I installed OS X yosemite.I did it on the standard partition, but I had a dual-boot with ubuntu.
I realised that the ubuntu boot was gone so I tried to redo it.
But in disk utility, when i tried to make Macintosh HD smaller it gave a
"Error: -69803: Couldn't modify partition map because file system verification failed
"

How do I fix this, not just for dual booting but resizing partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot holding  <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>R</kbd>  at the chimes to boot into Recovery Mode, run Disk Utility & Repair Disk.

Comment: Thank You.I tried Recovery mode but didn't know what repair disk did!